# Bash script containing sudo - unreliable background resume (bg)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sudo, job-control

I have the following simple bash script (called `test.sh`), that shows disk usage in the root dir. `sudo` is needed to list all directories (and I'm not asked for `sudo` password).

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo du -h --max-depth=1 / 2> /dev/null
```

The directory is in my path, and then I run the script like this (to get output to a text file):

```
$ ./test.sh >> ./test.txt
```

Now, if I suspend the job with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, I get this:

```
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./test.sh >> ./test.txt
```

If I then resume in background with `bg`, I still get:

```
$ bg
[1]+ ./test.sh >> ./test.txt &

[1]+  Stopped                 ./test.sh >> ./test.txt

$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 ./test.sh >> ./test.txt
```

*(Additional tries with `bg` may result in the script actually resuming in background after 2-3 tries, but it seems sporadic...)*

However, if I resume with `fg`, then the script runs in foreground:

```
$ fg
./test.sh >> ./test.txt
```

And the result is written to `test.txt`:

```
3.8M    /root
4.0K    /authentic-theme
4.0K    /srv
72K     /tmp
3.2G    /snap
4.0K    /media
8.4M    /etc
0       /proc
0       /sys
4.0K    /cdrom
16K     /opt
16K     /lost+found
24K     /dev
4.3M    /run
263G    /mnt
14M     /home
19G     /var
245M    /boot
3.8G    /usr
297G    /
```

If I modify the script to *not* use `sudo` (and instead run the script with `sudo`), then I can resume to background normally with `bg`, and the script is run:

```
$ sudo ./test.sh >> ./test.txt 
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sudo ./test.sh >> ./test.txt

$ bg
[1]+ sudo ./test.sh >> ./test.txt &

$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sudo ./test.sh >> ./test.txt &
```

The same happens if I run the entire command with `sudo`, but not as a script:

```
$ sudo du -h --max-depth=1 / 2> /dev/null >> ./test.txt
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sudo du -h --max-depth=1 / 2> /dev/null >> ./test.txt

$ bg
[1]+ sudo du -h --max-depth=1 / 2> /dev/null >> ./test.txt &

$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sudo du -h --max-depth=1 / 2> /dev/null >> ./test.txt &
```

Can anybody explain what's going on here? Why can you resume a command that uses `sudo` as well as a script in background, but when the script contains the exact same command using `sudo`, then background resume with `bg` is apparently not working correctly?

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 with default Bash version 5.1.16.

**Edit #1:** I can inform that I have setup `alias sudo='sudo '` to allow commands using `sudo` to use other aliases. However, I tested both with and without this alias, and I got the same erratic `bg` resume behavior in any case.*

**Edit #2:** `jobs -l` give the following normal information:

```
jobs -l
[1]+ 1074808 Stopped                 ./test.sh >> ./test.txt
```

**Edit #3:** I'm normally running in `tmux`, but I also tested without `tmux`, and the issue still persists.

**Edit #4:** Besides my SuperMicro server, I also has a Raspberry Pi, and an Ubuntu VM for testing on my Laptop (Aorus X5). This where it gets really strange:

- On my Ubuntu VM (on VMWare under Windows 10), this problem *does NOT* occur at all. It correctly resumes `bg` the first time in all cases.
- On my Raspberry Pi, the problem is present as well - it usually takes 2-3 tries with `bg` until it correctly resumes.

I'm beginning to think I need to test with regards to software that is running on both my main server and my Raspberry Pi, but not on my VM.

**Edit #5:** Setting `stty -tostop` before running the script unfortunately does not really help the problem. Most of the time, it still takes 2-3 tries to resume correctly. A few times it succeeds on the first try, but I think this is more chance than anything else.

**Edit #6:** These are the services running on my Raspberry Pi:

```
$ systemctl --type=service --state=running
  UNIT                             LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION                                            
  atd.service                      loaded active running Deferred execution scheduler
  containerd.service               loaded active running containerd container runtime
  cron.service                     loaded active running Regular background program processing daemon
  dbus.service                     loaded active running D-Bus System Message Bus
  docker.service                   loaded active running Docker Application Container Engine
  getty@tty1.service               loaded active running Getty on tty1
  irqbalance.service               loaded active running irqbalance daemon
  ModemManager.service             loaded active running Modem Manager
  networkd-dispatcher.service      loaded active running Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd
  packagekit.service               loaded active running PackageKit Daemon
  polkit.service                   loaded active running Authorization Manager
  prometheus-node-exporter.service loaded active running Prometheus exporter for machine metrics
  rsyslog.service                  loaded active running System Logging Service
  serial-getty@ttyS0.service       loaded active running Serial Getty on ttyS0
  smartmontools.service            loaded active running Self Monitoring and Reporting Technology (SMART) Daemon
  snapd.service                    loaded active running Snap Daemon
  ssh.service                      loaded active running OpenBSD Secure Shell server
  systemd-journald.service         loaded active running Journal Service
  systemd-logind.service           loaded active running User Login Management
  systemd-networkd.service         loaded active running Network Configuration
  systemd-timesyncd.service        loaded active running Network Time Synchronization
  systemd-udevd.service            loaded active running Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files
  udisks2.service                  loaded active running Disk Manager
  unattended-upgrades.service      loaded active running Unattended Upgrades Shutdown
  unbound.service                  loaded active running Unbound DNS server
  user@1000.service                loaded active running User Manager for UID 1000

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.
26 loaded units listed.
```

I believe these are the ones that I installed and activated (and are running on both the SuperMicro and the Raspberry Pi):

```
  containerd.service               loaded active running containerd container runtime
  docker.service                   loaded active running Docker Application Container Engine
  prometheus-node-exporter.service loaded active running Prometheus exporter for machine metrics
  smartmontools.service            loaded active running Self Monitoring and Reporting Technology (SMART) Daemon
  unbound.service                  loaded active running Unbound DNS server
```

**Things to test:**

- <s>Check if `sudo` configuration without `NOPASSWD` makes a difference.</s>
- Disable installed services that are common between my SuperMicro server and Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I can confirm that this happens no matter what command is used with `sudo` in the script (I tested with `sudo sleep 30`), and it isn't limited to Ubuntu (I tested on Arch). I think this is related to a recent change, I know I've seen questions about the behavior in the past few days.

Comment: I noticed that if I run `bg` a few times (it seems to vary between 1 in some cases, 2 in others and 3 in yet others, with the same command in the script) it eventually gets passed to the right process and the `sudo` command continues. Do you see the same behavior?

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Yes that is correct - if you try more times, it eventually succeeds - but the written output seems "interrupted" in a way..

Comment: It feels like there is some other process consuming the `bg` commands. Very strange.

Comment: I find it even more strange that the two other ways of doing the same thing with `sudo` succeeds every time. I actually tried a very thorough troubleshooting approach. So it is isolated when `sudo` is inside the script. 

Comment: Does `jobs -l` give you more information? FWIW I can't reproduce your issue (I'm also using ubuntu 22.04.1 and bash 5.1.16). I tried both your script and `sudo sleep 30`. I'm not experiencing the sporadic behaviour you mentioned.

Comment: @Dan what shell do you use? This will almost certainly be shell-specific. I reproduced it with bash `5.1.16(1)` which is the same as the OP's.

Comment: @terdon I use bash 5.1.16 as well

Comment: Does `stty -tostop` before running the script solve the problem? It's not a solution in itself but may help partition the problem

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't reproduce under Ubuntu 22.04 with Bash 5.1.16(1) on my system, but as you are probably aware, I'm running under WSL2.  So that counts as another possible counterexample of a "VM" not exhibiting the issue.  It also should be noted that I don't have Systemd or any other resulting services running in that instance either.  I'll see if I can load up some other environments where I might be able to repro, hoping we can find a common-denominator.

Comment: Thanks @NotTheDr01ds, much appreciated. 